# 2008 Mac Pro: Any chance of upgrading hardware to current technology?

Tags: mac, hardware, hardware-recommendation, mac-pro, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I upgrade my 2008 Mac Pro completely?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/can-i-upgrade-my-2008-mac-pro-completely)

I have a 2nd Gen 2008 Mac Pro 2.8ghz Quad Core with an 8800GT. I'm sure I can get away with the processing power and more RAM for now.

Is there any way possible I can put a modern day GPU inside this machine?

What does it entail to do such customizations?

Could I gut this machine and upgrade it fully to current technology?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be good to upgrade to a modern GPU (PCI-X). Keep in mind that you will need to purchase an 'Apple' version of any graphics card you upgrade to.